# Errors while invoking Web service using `Curl` command from Unix terminal

Tags: curl

I have been trying to invoke a web service from my script using the `Curl` command . I got the script from [HERE.](http://en.newinstance.it/2008/11/11/calling-webservice-at-the-unix-command-line/)

**My Script :**

```
#! /bin/sh

ENDPOINT="http://mathertel.de/AJAXEngine/S01_AsyncSamples/CalcService.asmx"
VALUE=1234567890
if [ -n "${1}" ]; then
    VALUE=${1}
fi

curl --silent \\
     --data \\
     @- \\
     --header 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' \\
     --user-agent "" \\
     ${ENDPOINT} <<EOF | xmllint --format -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <CalcPrimeFactors xmlns="http://www.mathertel.de/S01_AsyncSamples/">
      <inputText>${VALUE}</inputText>
    </CalcPrimeFactors>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
EOF
```

**And i get these Errors :**

```
./CalcService.sh: 10: ./CalcService.sh: --data: not found
./CalcService.sh: 11: ./CalcService.sh: @-: not found
./CalcService.sh: 12: ./CalcService.sh: --header: not found
./CalcService.sh: 13: ./CalcService.sh: --user-agent: not found
./CalcService.sh: 14: ./CalcService.sh: ./CalcService.sh: 14: ./CalcService.sh: http://mathertel.de/AJAXEngine/S01_AsyncSamples/CalcService.asmx: not found
 xmllint: not found
```

Now i have installed curl, and tried to install `xmllint` but it did not get installed, saying it's a broken package.

Anybody has any suggestions as to what is happening here and what i can do to mitigate this ? This is driving me crazy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @goldilocks suggested, taking out the double back slashes (`\\`) and replacing them with single backslashes (`\`) appears to fix your issue. Here's an example of the output with the modifications:

```
$ ./curl.bash 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <CalcPrimeFactorsResponse xmlns="http://www.mathertel.de/S01_AsyncSamples/">
      <CalcPrimeFactorsResult>2 3 3 5 3607 3803</CalcPrimeFactorsResult>
    </CalcPrimeFactorsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

#### A better method?

`curl` provides the following construct which can be used to pass options into it:

```
#!/bin/bash

{ echo '--opt1'
  echo '--opt2'
  ...
} | curl --config -
```

So you could adapt the above like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

ENDPOINT="http://mathertel.de/AJAXEngine/S01_AsyncSamples/CalcService.asmx"
VALUE=1234567890

if [ -n "${1}" ]; then
    VALUE=${1}
fi

read -r -d '' DATA <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <CalcPrimeFactors xmlns="http://www.mathertel.de/S01_AsyncSamples/">
      <inputText>${VALUE}</inputText>
    </CalcPrimeFactors>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
EOF

{
echo '--silent'
echo '--header "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"'
echo '--user-agent ""'
echo "--url ${ENDPOINT}"
echo '--data-binary @-'
echo "$DATA"
} | curl --config - | xmllint --format -
```

This construct makes it a little easier to parameterize the `$DATA` payloads so you could wrap the entire `curl` construct in a function and just pass it variables to include, for example.

Comment: I apologize for the late comment. Just checked out the nswer. You were quite right . I also installed the `libxml2` utility for xmllint. Everything is working just perfectly now. Thanks for the informative answer. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what shell you are using, but bash at least will crap out if you use `\\` to continue a line.  Try `\` instead.

WRT xml delinting, just check what you have with an online validator ([e.g. this one](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)) and use it.

Comment: I am using bash and thanks, i will try out u r suggestions.